MassTransit: Batch Consumer of an Amazon SQS FIFO queue
I'm trying to configure a batch consumer for an Amazon SQS FIFO queue with no success, the consumer is always triggered on a single message-basis.
I guess this could be a limitation of FIFO queues, but it would be nice to get feedback from others.
This is the code I'm using:
// Message:
public record BatchMessage();

// Consumer:
public class BatchMessageConsumer : IConsumer<Batch<BatchMessage>>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Batch<BatchMessage>> context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Messages={context.Message.Length}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

// ConsumerDefinition:
public class BatchMessageConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<BatchMessageConsumer>
{
    public BatchMessageConsumerDefinition()
    {
        // SQS Queue name.
        Endpoint(x => x.Name = $"Demo-BatchMessage.fifo");
    }
}

// Configuration:
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumers(typeof(Program).Assembly);

    x.UsingAmazonSqs((context, sqs) =>
    {
        sqs.Host("region", (_) => { });

        // SNS Topic name.
        sqs.Message<BatchMessage>(x => x.SetEntityName("BatchMessage.fifo"));

        sqs.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});

// Trigger:
var groupId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new BatchMessage(), (context) =>
    {
        // Required for FIFO messages.
        context.TrySetGroupId(groupId);
        context.TrySetDeduplicationId(context.MessageId.ToString());
    });
}


You should update your consumer definition to configure the transport for concurrency delivery of the same MessageGroupId:
// ConsumerDefinition:
public class BatchMessageConsumerDefinition : 
    ConsumerDefinition<BatchMessageConsumer>
{
    public BatchMessageConsumerDefinition()
    {
        // SQS Queue name.
        Endpoint(x => x.Name = $"Demo-BatchMessage.fifo");
    }

    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        IConsumerConfigurator<BatchMessageConsumer> consumerConfigurator, IRegistrationContext context)
    {
        consumerConfigurator.Options<BatchOptions>(o => o.SetMessageLimit(10).SetTimeLimit(1000));

        if(endpointConfigurator is IAmazonSqsReceiveEndpointConfigurator cfg)
        {
            cfg.ConcurrentDeliveryLimit = 5;
        }
    }
}


Works perfectly, ty!. Is this documented or stated somewhere? BTW, Is the "BatchOptions.GroupBy<T, TProperty>" still relevant for FIFO queues?

Oh, probably, yeah, you'll want to make sure it's used so the batches are maintained.
